# How to make a textarea behave like an input when the text in it reaches the end of the line?

Tags: html, css

I have a one line (row) textarea and I want it to behave like an input when the text in it reaches the end of the line.

If this is my textarea:

```
--------------
|input text h|
--------------
```

The next character(s) will cause the textarea to do this:

```
--------------
|ere         |
--------------
```

The rest of the text is in the line above which is hidden because my textarea has `rows="1"`.

What I'd like it to do is:

```
--------------
|ut text here|
--------------
```

Which is how an input would have behaved.

Here's a codepen for it to play around with: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zEJVWW

I tried to change the `overflow` and `overflow-x` css attributes but that had no effect.
Any ideas?

(I wasn't able to find a question about this, but probably because I wasn't sure what exactly to search for, if it exists I'd be happy to mark as duplicate.)

---

#### Edit

The reason I want to do this is that my textarea should behave as an input until the user presses the enter key (or something similar).
That is, I want to be the one who controls if and when the line breaks into a new one.

Comment: May I ask why you want a `<textarea>` to behave exactly like an `<input>` and why not use an `<input>` field then?

Comment: @caramba Right, forgot to address that, please see my edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 5px 2px;
}

.box {
  width: 60px;
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box2 {
  resize: none;
}

/* added only these styles to the ones you had */
textarea {
  height: 15px;
  white-space: pre;
  overflow-wrap: normal;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  input: <input class="box box1" value="input text h" />
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  textarea: <textarea class="box box2" rows="1">input text h</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this does it!  I only changed to `overflow-x: hidden` as I don't want to scrollbar, and then there's also no need for the `height: 15px`.

Comment: @NitzanTomer nice, glad it helped! Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if my understand is correct, but if you change the CSS class to

```
.box2 {
  resize: none;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  word-wrap:unset;
}
```

So we can remove the word wrapping and set `overflow-x:hidden` and it will behave like an input element, please let me know if this is whats needed.

<kbd>**Codepen Demo**</kbd>

Comment: It behaves the same with your code, when I enter another character it break the line

Comment: @NitzanTomer Just for understanding purpose, where was my code failing with respect to the correct answer :)

Comment: With your code (when I try it in the codepen link you added), when I add another character in the textarea then the last word drops to the next line which is exactly what I was trying to avoid. The answer by @caramba solves it.

Comment: @NitzanTomer Ok maybe I gave the wrong link or something, it doesn't happen for me :) no problem, glad you fixed your issue!

Comment: I also tried to just copy the style changes you suggested and it did not work for me. Maybe a browser thing? I'm using chrome 61

Comment: @NitzanTomer I am on the same version too :D

Comment: Then I don't know why we get different results

Comment: @NitzanTomer Its ok, Happy coding!